# Is there a short form for this css selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've stumbled across this many times before and I've been wondering if one could write this in a simpler and less redundant way.

**Let's assume we have this HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapperClass">
    <div class="someClass">
        <h1>This is a title</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I want to style the `<h1>` element I'd proceed like that:

```
.wrapperClass .someClass h1 { 
    color: red;
}
```

Let's assume there is also a possibility that the user uses a `<h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5> or even a <h6>` and we need to cover these cases as well.

**My CSS statement would now look like this:**

```
.wrapperClass .someClass h1, .wrapperclass .someClass h2, .wrapperClass .someClass h3 ...
```

This statement is really long; that's why I'm wondering whether there is a **short form for these sort of cases** or not.

Comment: Take a look at LESS or SASS

Comment: This isn't really possible in standard CSS, and it's one of the reason why CSS preprocessors like LESS and SASS becomes popular.

Comment: CSS4 has this sorted - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(Currently) there is no *any heading* selector but an alternative with certain restrictions is this:

```
.wrapperClass .someClass > *
```

It will match ***any*** element that is a direct child of `.someClass`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Sass:

```
.wrapperClass {
  .someClass { 
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using with CSS and Sass/Scss.

```css
/* Using space means any of its child element */
.className * {                <element class="className">
    pointer-events:none;        …
}                                 <element>
/* Using `>` symbol means immediate child element */
.className > * {              <element class="className">
    pointer-events:none;        <element>
}

.list > ul > li:only-child  {color:red}
.list > ul > li:first-child {color:green}
.list > ul > li:last-child  {color:blue}

.list > ul > li:nth-child(2)       {color:blue}
.list > ul > li:not(.className)    {color:blue}
```

> [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) define the elements to which a set of CSS rules apply.

`Child combinator`[A > B] « The `>` combinator selects nodes that are direct children of the first element.

`Descendant combinator`[A B] « The  (space) combinator selects nodes that are descendants of the first element.

`Universal selector`[*] « `*` will match all the elements of the document.

> [`Sass`](https://sass-lang.com/guide) « CSS with superpowers

When writing HTML you've probably noticed that it has a clear nested and visual hierarchy. CSS, on the other hand, doesn't.

```scss
.className {
    .className2 {
        color: red;
        width: 600px / 960px * 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip one parent class of child element and specific element needs to apply, don't apply for all elements. Specific elements it's finding fast compare than a Universal selector.

```
.someClass h1, .someClass h2, ....{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Sass to make this easier, here is your example using a Sass for loop:

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    .wrapperClass .someClass h#{$i} {
        color: red;
  }
}
```

Paste that snippet into the Sass playground here to check the output: https://www.sassmeister.com/